# Either all vectors of a vector space are eigenvectors or none for rotation matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Orthogonal matrices represent rotations or reflection. In the case it represents rotation, every vector in the space is rotated and is knocked off their span, so there is no eigenvectors?

Or if it is rotated 180 degrees, then every vector is in their span, so is every vector an eigenvector?

Comment: Do you consider $3$ or higher dimension rotations?

Comment: More information needed.  For instance, a rotation of $\mathbb R^2$ will have no real eigenvectors and two complex eigenvectors - do you count these? - except in the case of a rotation through $180n$ degrees.  A rotation of $\mathbb R^3$ will have one real eigenvector (up to scalar multiples) and two complex, with a similar exception.

Comment: Considering only 2d transformation

Comment: So what happens in case of 180n degree rotations? Infinite eigenvectors?

Comment: The matrix representing a 180-degree rotation in the plane is $$A=\pmatrix{-1&0\cr0&-1\cr}$$, so $Av=-v$ for all $v$.

Comment: There are always infinite eigenvectors, since any multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector for the same eigenvalue. However, $I$ and $-I$ are orthogonal matrices for which every vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ for $I$, and $-1$ for $-I$. For 2D, no other rotation matrices have a real eigenvalue.